# How to append ruby code to html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm making a chat using `ActionController::live`.
 `stream` in my ChatsController pushes posts.

```
def stream
  response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'
  start = Time.zone.now
  loop do
    Post.where('created_at > ?', start).each do |post|
    response.stream.write("event:push\n")
    response.stream.write("data:#{post.to_json}\n\n")
    start = post.created_at
    end
    sleep 2
  end
rescue IOError
ensure
  response.stream.close
end
```

Using javascript, I wrap gravatar and this json with `<li>` and append this to `<ul>`. Then, I want to use `gravatar_for` method I defined and render partial for `post` model.

Would you teach me how to append ruby code (<%...%>) to html elements(

)? I tried to `.append('<%...%>')` once, it didn't work.

Comment: Can you share your Model and partial code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your controller is responding to javascript, you can render a partial using  from the corresponding js.erb file like so:

```
$('element').append('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: "post") %>');
```